# How can I set the minimum size of an MPart in Eclipse4?

Tags: eclipse, size, min, e4

I am working with Eclipse4 and I want to set the minimum size for an MPart. I know I can set it for the whole application window, I found a way to do that here: [How to restrict the minimum size of the window for Eclipse e4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15894393/how-to-restrict-the-minimum-size-of-the-window-for-eclipse-e4) ,but I want to do it for a specific part inside the window.
An answer will be greatly appreciated! 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't see any existing support for this. So you would probably have to use a renderer factory to create a custom sash renderer which uses a new sash layout. The existing sash layout does limit the minimum size to 10% of the sash area.

Comment: Ok...I did notice there was an existing limitation for the minimum width and it was based on percentage...I am not 100% on how to create a custom sash renderer, but I will try...thank you!

Comment: I think you should probably be able to extend the existing `SashRenderer` and change the layout in the `createWidget` method rather than doing a renderer from scratch (which is hard).